# Handling crash report with Crashlytics framework provided incorrect crashDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm using `Crashlytics` framework as a crash handler in may iOS app.

I need to send information of the crash to my server and to do this I implemented the delegate of `[Crashlytics sharedInstance]` method called

It provides the way to handle crash report at your application start to decide whether it should send that crash report or not. Below is simplest implementation of that kind of method:

```
- (void)crashlyticsDidDetectReportForLastExecution:(CLSReport *)report completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler {
    NSDate *crashDate = report.dateCreated;
    //Do the logic
    completionHandler(YES);
}
```

To test if everything work as expected I simulated the crash using these lines

```
{
    ...
    NSDate *realCrashDate = [NSDate date];
    [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash];
}
```

And then I noticed that `realCrashDate` that I printed in the log right before crash is different to `crashDate` stored in `CLSReport` instance.
And the difference is even weirder because `crashDate` is earlier than `realCrashDate`.

Real examples are:

```
realCrashDate = 2016-02-15 14:36:21 +0000
crashDate = 2016-02-15 14:36:01 +0000
```

Does it the bug in `Crashlytics` framework or it's something that I don't understand right.

Comment: The `LastExecution` part of the delegate method name sounds like a clue?  In other words it's the crash that ended the *previous* run of the app?  I am guessing really, but I know that there is a delay between a crash and the reporting of a crash when I used Crashlytics and it wouldn't appear until I restarted the app.

Comment: @trojanfoe you are right, the delegate method is invoked on the next application launch, probably I should have mentioned that. But this still is not the answer to the question, since the date must be the same +/- couple of ms. But not that huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. Seems like the `report.dateCreated` returns not the date of crash but the date of application session start.

This is really confusing. I guess Crashlytics team should have named it differently or at least mention it in the interface doc.